# Fresh Gerbera Can't Start?

Tags: gerbera

I just installed Gerbera on my Ubuntu Server downstairs and tried to start it using `gerbera`. It generated a config file first, then gave this error:

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ gerbera 
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Gerbera UPnP Server version 1.1.0 - http://gerbera.io/
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: ===============================================================================
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Gerbera is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License version 2
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Copyright 2016-2017 Gerbera Contributors.
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Gerbera is based on MediaTomb: Copyright 2005-2010 Gena Batsyan, Sergey Bostandzhyan, Leonhard Wimmer.
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: ===============================================================================
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Loading configuration from: /home/sarah/.config/gerbera/config.xml
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Checking configuration...
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Setting filesystem import charset to UTF-8
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Setting metadata import charset to UTF-8
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Setting playlist charset to UTF-8
2019-05-19 05:42:33 WARNING: You enabled the YouTube feature, which allows you
                             to watch YouTube videos on your UPnP device!
                             Please check http://www.youtube.com/t/terms
                             By using this feature you may be violating YouTube
                             service terms and conditions!

2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Configuration check succeeded.
Exception raised in [src/server.cc:123] upnp_init(): upnp_init: UpnpInit failed
2019-05-19 05:42:33   ERROR: main: upnp error -203
2019-05-19 05:42:33   ERROR: Could not bind to socket.
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: Please check if another instance of Gerbera or
2019-05-19 05:42:33    INFO: another application is running on port 0.
2019-05-19 05:42:33   ERROR: upnp_cleanup: UpnpUnRegisterRootDevice failed
Exception raised in [src/server.cc:248] shutdown(): upnp_cleanup: UpnpUnRegisterRootDevice failed
```

Not sure why.

Strange thing is that the gerbera service is up and running:

```
● gerbera.service - Gerbera Media Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gerbera.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-05-19 05:40:08 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:gerbera(1)
           https://gerbera.io/
 Main PID: 28343 (gerbera)
    Tasks: 12 (limit: 4467)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gerbera.service
           └─28343 /usr/bin/gerbera -c /etc/gerbera/config.xml

May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08    INFO: Setting playlist charset to UTF-8
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08 WARNING: You enabled the YouTube feature, which allows you
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]:                              to watch YouTube videos on your UPnP device!
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]:                              Please check http://www.youtube.com/t/terms
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]:                              By using this feature you may be violating YouTube
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]:                              service terms and conditions!
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08    INFO: Configuration check succeeded.
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08    INFO: Initialized port: 49152
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08    INFO: Server bound to: 192.168.1.222
May 19 05:40:08 scilab_comp_0 gerbera[28343]: 2019-05-19 05:40:08    INFO: The Web UI can be reached by following this link: http://192.168.1.222:49152/
```

Am I using gerbera incorrectly? How can I get it working and watch a folder for media?

Answer (score 0):

After installation on ubuntu, gerbera is automatically started as a deamon process (via user `gerbera`). In order to start it manually, you have to kill the daemon process, e.g.

```
ps aux | grep gerbera
sudo kill <pid>
```

Comment: I have the same message, but gerbera doesn't run (ps ax | gerbera shows nothing)